# Different cell protection in the same Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Inside an Excel worksheet, I would like to protect a cell (A1) from Editing and another cell (B1) from Formatting. This means that the user:

- can't edit the value of A1
- can edit the value of B1
- can't change the formatting of B1

The "Protect Sheet" option allows to protect all locked cells of an entire Sheet, so A1 and B1, when locked, would have the same protection level (either against formatting or editing).

Is there a way to set individual protections for a specific cell or range, or at least obtain the same behaviour?

Additional info:

- A solution using VBA is OK (though it looks that the Worksheet.Protect Method has the same limitations...)
- The cell A1 (for which Edit must be prevented) can be protected against Formatting or not (it doesn't matter).
- It should work with Excel 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locked doesn't address formatting as long as you don't have the allow format cells checked or activated in vba.  Therefore you can simply unlock B1 and you wont be able to edit the format with just allowing users to select locked and unlocked cells enabled.

```
Sub protectorate()

    activesheet.Range("B1").Locked = False

    With ActiveSheet
        .Protect
    End With


End Sub
```

This will prevent formatting and value changes on the entire sheet except the value of B1, it will still let you edit the value of B1.

Comment: Yes! It was so simple! :-) But this also means that I can't have different **Formatting** protections inside the same sheet: either formattable or not formattable at all. I hope I'll never need it... @brettdj: yes, it also works setting the Locked properties for the Cell without using VBA.

Comment: @brettdj It can be done through the menu.  I suppose its personal habit to do protection through vba.  I'll edit with better instructions for doing this through the menu

Comment: @RustyGear if you want to be able to edit some formats, you can do that by letting them format all cells, but not be able to select locked cells.  This assumes that you would let them format and change the value of the same cells.