# Protect specific area in excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, user-input, spreadsheet-protection

I wanna proctect a specific area or only rows in a excel sheet where the user can make changes.

[image: My Excel Sheet]

the red area should be protected, is this possible and realizeable with vba? And is it possible to make the protec **scalable**, when the user insert a new line?

Thanks for your suggestion!, I know my english is no quite good... -.-

I know ther are exist many question about this subject but i didn't found the right answer in following question:

- [How to protect cells in Excel but allow...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/how-to-protect-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script)
- [Different cell protection in...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642569/different-cell-protection-in-the-same-worksheet)

I hope you can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to pick which cells aren't protected by setting the Locked to false

```
Worksheets("Main").Range("B2:E4").Locked = False
```

Then you have to use to modify the cells

```
Worksheets("Main").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Comment: But when he insert a row the proctection will protect an other cell wich should no be protected?

Comment: From what I know you can't protect ranges from being edited while allowing scalability.

Comment: and you think it is not possible to make that a little bit scalable?